# Autosize knockout custom binding autosize on load

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, autosize

I have a custom [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) binding for [jquery autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize) that I want to have autosize on page load.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/armandvdwalt/3p9bj/1/) of the issue

Example of code:

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.autogrow = {

 init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

     ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'focusout', function () {
         var observable = valueAccessor();
         observable($(element).val());
     });

     ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
         $(element).data('autosize').remove();
     });

     $(element).autosize({ append: "\n" });

     $(element).focus(function () {
         $(element).trigger('autosize');
     });
 },

 update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
     var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
     $(element).val(value);
     $(element).trigger("autosize");
   }
};

var vm = {};
vm.Data = ko.observable("This is a lot of text and has to display correctly");

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Example of html:

```
<textarea id="autogrow" class="text-nm span2" data-bind="autogrow: Data"></textarea>
```

What happens is I have a lot of text that I want to display in a text area but the amount differs every time, so I have no set amount that will display that I know before hand. What I want to do is after the knockout bindings have been applied I want to trigger the autosize event of the autosize plug in, but I can't figure out when and where.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've might misunderstood the question, but this works in FF atleast

http://jsfiddle.net/3p9bj/13/

I removed the update function and let autosize do its thing under the hood

I also use the value binding for updating value

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: valueAccessor() });
```

Comment: The above example doesn't work because the path to the jquery auto resize is resolving to 404.  Even with the correct path this works on first load but appears to collapse when trying to type in the text area.  Not sure about the poster but this is what I needed for auto sizing. http://jsfiddle.net/3p9bj/24/