# knockout autogrow binding removes change event binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, custom-binding, autogrow

I have a custom binding for a jquery autogrow plugin that can be seen here [Autosize knockout custom binding autosize on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062712/autosize-knockout-custom-binding-autosize-on-load)

The code for reference:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autogrow = {

            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: valueAccessor() });

                ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                    //$(element).data('autosize').remove();
                });

                $(element).autosize({ append: "\n" });

                $(element).focus(function () {
                    $(element).trigger('autosize');
                });
            }
        };
```

I am using it as follows:

```
 <textarea id="autogrow" class="text-nm span2" data-bind="autogrow: AreaProcessName, attr: { id: 'AreaProcessName' + Id }, event: { change: ViewModel.vmAreaProcess.SetAreaRevision($data) }"></textarea>
```

The attr binding is still working but the event binding on change has stopped working.

Any ideas?

Comment: does it work normally if you don't have the autogrow on it? also, change your binding for the event from change: ViewModel.vmAreaProcess.SetAreaRevision($data) to change: ViewModel.vmAreaProcess.SetAreaRevision you don't need to pass in $data, that will immediately execute the function

Comment: @SujeshArukil Hi, yes it works as expected when I remove the autogrow part

Comment: what are you trying to get from the change event? the value inside the textarea being passed to a function?

Comment: No I need the whole object

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/3p9bj/17/ this seems to be working fine. All I did was remove the ($data) from the change event.

Comment: @SujeshArukil any reason for this? Just tested in my code and works. Can you put it as answer so I can mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/3p9bj/17 
this seems to be working fine. All I did was remove the ($data) from the change event. The reason as I pointed out in my first comment is when you set something like

```
data-bind="event: {'someevent': func()}
```

what essentially is happening is, the even handler for someevent is being set as the return of func() call. Since your function ViewModel.vmAreaProcess.SetAreaRevision is not returning a handler function, it will not do a callback when the even is actually fired because the func() is executed immediately.

when you set it like this

```
data-bind="event: {'someevent': func}
```

you are actually binding 'someevent' to func handler. the func will be executed when the event is fired. Hope that clears it?